# jQuery run function after done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to run a function after a function is completely done. I read that this does the trick.

```
 $.when(functionName1()).done(
    $.when(functionName2()).done(
      functionName3()
     )
 );
```

The problem is that the previous functions aren't finished loading yet. I think the cause is because there are a couple ajax calls in the previous functions.

How can I make sure that all ajax calls and the function has completely finished before moving onto the next function?

Comment: Use promises which will make this async thing easier

Comment: Use anonymous function `$.when(functionName1()).done(function () {
    $.when(functionName2()).done(functionName3);
});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use done method for step by step move,

```
 $.when(functionName1()).done(function () {
      $.when(functionName2()).done(functionName3); 
    });
```